# Connection time out while connecting to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, timeout, amazon-web-services, connection

I am a new user of amazon web services and trying to learn to use the services.

I used the getting started EC2 guide to create and connect to an EC2 instance (trying to be within the free usage tier).

I am able to create the EC2 instance for both Linux and windows, but I am not been able to connect to the running instance. I followed the instruction given in the getting started guide but still not getting any positive results. I used the MindTree tool as well as the putty to connect to running Linux instance. For window server, I tried the RDP connection with the running instance.

I am getting connection time out error in MindTree, putty, and window RDP on window instance. I checked the security setting of the instance and port 22 (ssh) was enabled for the Linux instance and port 3389 (RDP) was enabled for the window instance.

Please help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the corporate LAN that was blocking the SSH and RDP traffic. I tried it in my home network and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Is you local firewall blocking your traffic to those ports perhaps?

Comment: I disabled the firewall and then again try to connect to the ec2 but still no success.

Comment: Also I am able to ping and tracert the EC2 instance. But when I try to connect using SSH it gives me the connection timeout error. I also checked the system logs for SSH service and the sshd service was getting started successfully...

Answer (score 1):

Login to Amazon aws -> click instance -> under instance click Description tab -> Check the security groups -> view rules.

-> View rules must be like this

```
Ports   Protocol    Source     default
All      All        sg-yourid   ✔
22       tcp        0.0.0.0/0   ✔
```

-> If your view rules doesn't have 22 port, then click security groups -> edit -> add type = SSH, Source =All.